# What happens to a Docker container when a volume is stored on a cifs mount that loses connection?

Tags: docker, mount

This is related to my home server setup, where I have a NAS server and two Ubuntu 16.04 LTS hosts running several docker containers. Both hosts have cifs mounts to locations on the NAS and several of the docker containers have volume mounts on those cifs mounts.

The NAS firmware/software requires updating from time to time, and while trying to come up with an update procedure that requires the least amount of manual intervention on my part, I find myself wondering what would happen if the Ubuntu hosts were to lose the cifs connection while the containers are running.

For instance, when VMWare ESXi loses an iSCSI mount, it suspends any machines that were using it. Would Docker do anything similar? Would it act as if those volume mounts were suddenly empty?

I'm not necessarily looking for a better way to perform my NAS updates, I could surely stop all of the containers and `mount -a` after the update, but it would be nice to know how this NAS-based setup could affect my containers.

Comment: Well, why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh, I'll get around to it at some point and report back if this doesn't get an answer. Both servers have Plex containers running that are in use a lot, so I need to let folks know they'll be down for a bit when I do. I'm also a little concerned about screwing up my data trying it out, but I'll take those lumps if it comes to it.

Comment: Well, you said it's a home server, so we don't really expect anything serious to be running on it, and we also [expect you to not ask about home servers here](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well damn, I did miss that. Figured it wasn't really a question for SuperUser either since my home network is mostly business-grade stuff from work, not consumer. Apologies, feel free to close this, anyone who might have an answer can find me at this Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/5vsgy2/what_happens_to_a_docker_container_when_a_volume/